# Regular expression for MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table emp_skills which has emp_id and skill_id as two columns. Now,

```
SELECT * FROM emp_skills where skill_id REGEXP '^[2,3]$'
```

outputs emp_id's of those who have either 2 or 3 or both. What I want is emp_id's of those which have both 2 and 3 as their skill_id's. Skill_id is Integer

Example output of above query

```
EMP_ID     SKILL_ID
401        2   
405        2
401        3
405        3
407        3
```

Now what is I want is only first four rows as 407 does not have 2 as skill_id

Comment: what is the data type of column `skill_id`? and how are values stored in it?

Comment: 'both 2 and 3 as their skill_id's': What do you mean exactly? Please add an example to your question.

Comment: It's probably '^(23|32)$' or '^(2[^0-9]*3|3[^0-9]*2)$', depending on the data format.

Comment: @BundleContext.. you dont need to use regex for this, try my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your phrase `both 2 and 3 as their skill_id`, i think you don't need `regex` for this. All you need are only `count`, `group by` and `having`

```
SELECT EMP_ID
FROM emp_skills
WHERE skill_ID IN (2,3)     
GROUP BY EMP_ID
HAVING COUNT(EMP_ID) = 2    -- the total number of skill_ID
```

you need to match the number of records with the total number of id supplied in the `where` clause.

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49409/2)

Comment: @BundleContext.. you're welcome, i also added sqlfiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `skill_id` as `INTEGER` column, then this can be easily achieved by using `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp_skills 
WHERE skill_id IN(2,3);
```